# Validate dynamically created textbox to enter only numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-text

I have created textbox dynamically which goes on adding on button click which is working fine, but now I want to validate that each textbox which is dynamically created should take only numerical data as input.

How can I do that? I have not used jQuery to create textbox dynamically but used C# in asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [`CompareValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx),

> Compares the value entered by the user in an input control with the
>   value entered in another input control, or with a constant value.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Type="Integer"
   Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="Wrong value. Value must be an integer!" />
```

As an alternative, you can use [`RegularExpressionValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) with `"\d+"` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class in your dynamically created  textbox see code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server CssClass="numeric" />
```

client side code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.numeric').keyup(function () {
                    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
                });
        });
 </script>
```

How many textbox you add dynamically it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can add the rule to each item matched by the wildcard selector with `.each()`, like this:

```
$("#SubmitForm").validate();
$("input[id*=Hours]").each(function() {
$(this).rules("add", {
    number: true,
    messages: {
        number: "Please enter a valid Hours"
    }
});
});
```